# Did or do you have a hard time when you first try to solve problems in anlysis? I feel stucked.

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

I am junior in college major in math, studying Real analysis 4th edition, Royden.

At first, my professor just explains concepts and keeps going on without solving any problem in the book or else.

I respect my professor, she may have a mind for teaching, since she has devoted her life for studying and teaching analysis, and will be retired after 2 or 3 years.

I do really hard on studying real analysis these days, I think. Especially solving problems in the book. But it is really hard for me to solve them.

In fact, I studied really hard on understanding and proving proposition of measures or something, but aftet that, when I try to solve problems, then I can do nothing.

So I cannot help searching Google for solutions for problems. When I see them, I can understand how it works. But without solution, I am nothing. I can't do anything on solving problems.

For Modern Algebra, I feel more comfortable to solve problems. If I understand the concepts of it, then I can solve problems almost all of them in the book.

So, did or do you have a hard time for solving problems in analysis book? Or just I am not good at math? is it just only my problem?

I studied really hard these days, so I have sore eyes and stress out and chain smoke for today... because of analysis. REALLY Stressed out..

So I feel really stucked, I cannot help posting this....

What can I do? Studying with solution is okay?

I want to really be good at math....

Comment: They're called tutors. Most universities provide them for free,

Comment: @StevenGregory Well, Sadly, my university does not provide them..... My university provides just for Calculus or Engineering mathetmatics... but they are my friends, with the same shoes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have know that. Real analysis can be pretty tough. I still suggest a tutor, though I know that money is a problem  for most students. MSE would be glad to help you, provided that you can show some evidence that you tried something and then got stuck.

Comment: @StevenGregory It's okay. By the way, what is MSE?

Comment: MSE = Math StackEschange

Comment: @StevenGregory Oh I see.... Actually when I googling, there are many posts from MSE, so I get many information from them.

Comment: You say when you see the solutions, you understand them. Can you repeat the solutions back later from memory? Can you teach other people the solutions that you do understand? Can you figure out plausible scenarios by which someone could have found the solution from scratch? These are good litmus tests to tell if you really understand something. It's more than just following along one logical step at a time, or memorizing lines - in order to remember and articulate proofs, you really need to understand the *ideas* behind the proofs. When you see new problems, try to find the *idea* behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have discussion sections? If yes, make sure that TA does solve problems in class (not the homework problems but problems from the textbook) and ask him/her how did he/she came up with the solutions. If not, team up with some of your classmates and work on problems together. In your case, most likely, it is a matter of practicing a lot. Assuming you have a textbook (I assume you do) with a list of problems in the end of each section of the book, work on these problems yourself or with your classmates. The problems tend to be testing if you understand concepts and theorems from the section just covered (although they also tend to build up on the material of the previous sections). One more thing to remember "**algebra is about equations, analysis is about inequalities**". (OK, as all rules, this one is true only up to a point, but still...) In particular, make sure you are good with inequalities (being able to solve inequalities, knowing various "standard" inequalities like Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, Jensen inequality, etc). If you have hard time remembering the standard  inequalities, make a list and look at it every day.

Comment: No discussion sections and also TA is my friend with the same shoes of me...  

In fact, I am shy and also I love to study alone.... Also, My friends just study problems from last year exam, from student who took this course last year. Well as I said I am shy and I really hate studying only for exam. I just want to be good at math.

So, I want to ask that how about studying analysis with solutions and this site.

Comment: @JAEMTO: This sounds bad, there are many advantages in studying with friends or just classmates. One is that you can ask the question "how did you came up with the solution?" If you really are unable to work with somebody else, consider solving analysis problems from MSE (which already have solutions) and then comparing your solutions with the ones from the MSE.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to work with my classmates, and with MSE....